# Script should run when matched with URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whole day I have been trying to get my script working on a specific website.
Basically I want this script to only run on specific domains.

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    // URL variables
    let fullURL = window.location.host;
    let fullURL2 = window.location.host + window.location.pathname;

    var timer = setInterval(deletor, 1);

        alert(fullURL2);
        alert(fullURL);

        if (fullURL === "net.adjara.com") {

                function deletor() {
                timer;

                    var slider = document.querySelector("#slider-con");
                    var bannerTop = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(2)")
                    var bannerMiddle = document.querySelector("#MainContent > iframe");
                    var bannerRandom = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(3)");

                        if (slider) {
                            slider.parentNode.removeChild(slider);
                        }

                        if (bannerTop) {
                            bannerTop.parentNode.removeChild(bannerTop);
                        }

                        if (bannerMiddle) {
                            bannerMiddle.parentNode.removeChild(bannerMiddle);
                        }

                        if (bannerRandom) {
                            bannerRandom.parentNode.removeChild(bannerRandom);
                        }

                        console.log("worked!");
                };

        } else {
            console.log("false!");
            return false;
        }

});
```

I do get "false" console logged when I go to other site than mentioned, but the script doesn't execute when the domain matches. I even added an alert to see what the value was of the variable and copy-pasted that.

Comment: Well you use deletor before it is defined, that seems like a bad idea

Comment: `setInterval(deletor, 1);` <== one millisecond is a crazy short time for an interval.  I can't imagine this not causing issues.

Comment: The interval doesn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function is defined inside the if, the variable will be hoisted, but it will not have a value

```js
console.log(test)
if (new Date()){
  function test() {}
}
```

so you are setting the interval with undefined.

Move the interval after you define the function.